# How could I check to see if the next element in an array is the same name as the current element

Tags: jquery

I have an array and I'm trying to check to see if the array in the next slow is the same as the current slow in the array.

Here is my logic so far:

```
$("#container").append("<table border='1' id='main-table'></table>");       
                var strNames = ["dennis", "dennis", "d00d", "sweet"].sort();
                var categories = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < strNames.length; i++) {

                    if (strNames[i] == strNames[i+1])
                        categories[i] = strNames[i];

                    console.log(categories[i]);
                    if (categories.length  > 1) {
                        $("#main-table").append("<tr class='main-table-row'><td><div class='expandTableCell' toggle='false'></div></td></tr>"); 
                        for (var x = 0; x < categories.length; x++)
                            if (x == 0)
                                $("#main-table tr.main-table-row td div.expandTableCell").append("<div class='expandTableCellHeader'>" + categories[x] + "</div>");
                            else
                                $("#main-table tr.main-table-row td div.expandTableCell").append("<div class='expandTableCellData'>" + categories[x] + "</div>");
                    } else
                        $("#main-table").append("<tr class='main-table-row'><td>" + strNames[i] + "</tr>");
                }
```

I need it to check the next index of an array and if it has the same name, store it into categories which ends up building a tree. If you need more information I can try to provide more.

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: Ah yes this question was kind of hard to ask, I need help with storing the correct values into the categories array.

Comment: Are you trying to only keep duplicates? Or just if the current one matches the next?

Comment: nope, it takes the duplicates and puts them in a category, so it's dynamically building a table, each td contains a div with the category inside of it, so if you see "dennis", "dennis" it will create a category called "dennis" and under that category you will see a child "dennis"

Comment: one of the issues i see is that your `categories[]` array doesn't have its indexes in order, so when you hit it with your `x < categories.length` loop it generates a lot of `undefined` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change your logic a bit, but here you go:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruy7R/3/)**

```
$("#container").append("<table border='1' id='main-table'></table>");

var strNames = ["dennis", "dennis", "d00d", "sweet"].sort();
var categories = [];

for (var i = 0; i < strNames.length; i++) {
    var name = strNames[i];
    if (typeof(categories[name]) == 'undefined') categories[name] = 1;
    else categories[name] += 1;
}

for (var name in categories) {
    var val = categories[name];
    if (val > 1) {
        $("#main-table").append("<tr class='main-table-row'><td><div class='expandTableCell' toggle='false'></div></td></tr>");
        for (var x = 0; x < val; x++)
            if (x == 0) $("#main-table tr.main-table-row td div.expandTableCell").append("<div class='expandTableCellHeader'>" + name + "</div>");
            else $("#main-table tr.main-table-row td div.expandTableCell").append("<div class='expandTableCellData'>" + name + "</div>");
    } else $("#main-table").append("<tr class='main-table-row'><td>" + name + "</tr>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was having a hard time explaining how I wanted this to work, and you hit it on the head :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

> if (strNames[i] == strNames[i+1])
>                           categories[i] = strNames[i];

will fail when i points to the last element of the 'strNames' array. An exception will be thrown, since i+1 will point out of the array.

Otherwise, I do not see any problem on this "if". To avoid this error you need to make your for loop to be something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < strNames.length-1; i++)
```

I also see another problem in the 'if' comparison `if (categories.length > 1)`

Doesn't it have to be `if (categories.length >= 1)` ? If you leave it as it is, then when categories length is 1, then block is not entered.

Comment: It's set to > 1 because if the category only has one item just print that, if great than, add a class and such to expand and contract the categories.

Answer (score 0):

Other than doing this:

```
if (i + 1 < strNames.length 
    i + 1 < categories.length 
    && categories[i] == strNames[i+1])
```

You should be on your way